# Compare value of month and timestamp

Tags: mongodb

I have created a mongodb which looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ece47aa6510a611b47aac5a"),
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ece47aa6510a611b47aac6e"),
            "timestamp" : "1470420945250",
            "type" : "f1"
        }, 
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5ece47aa6510a611b47a8895"),
           "timestamp" : "1470420945250"
           "type" : "f2"
        },
        {..},
```

{..}
]
Now i am trying to make a query to match the timestamps above with a specific month. Something like this:

```
const types = await Location.aggregate([ 
    {    
          $match:{
            "array.timestamp" : 09
           }
     }
])
```

How can i compare the value of the timestamp with the month Semptember for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

- convert string time stamp to number format using `$toLong`, convert timestamp to date format using `$toDate`, get month form date using `$month`,
- `$filter` to get matching month array in `arrayMonth`
- `$match` condition is `arrayMonth` array not blank
- `$project` to remove `arrayMonth` field if not needed

```
const types = await Location.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      arrayMonth: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$array",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              9, // add filter month here 
              { $month: { $toDate: { $toLong: "$$this.timestamp" } } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { arrayMonth: { $ne: [] } } },
  { $project: { arrayMonth: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LpyIQt8sYRO)

---

Second same query, you can combine above stages in single using `$expr` in `$match`,

```
const types = await Location.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          [],
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$array",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  9, // add your month filter
                  { $month: { $toDate: { $toLong: "$$this.timestamp" } } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OzkIZ3vcB6k)